# USB Stick with the latest distro packages.

Tags: 15.04, live-usb

Let us suppose that I download the Ubuntu 15.04 ISO file from the website, and using the USB Disk creator or UNetBootin, create a USB Stick.

Now is it possible to update the USB stick with the latest packages so that in the next installation, the latest kernel version and packages get installed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/60406/how-to-upgrade-your-ubuntu-iso-without-re-downloading/) describes a way to upgrade an iso file without re-downloading it.